# EPiServer - href to "Content" of a ContentReference property?

Tags: href, episerver

Greeting all EPiServer gurus.

Environment: EPiServer 7.

**Description of problem:**

*I have a PageType with different properties. One of the properties is a ContentReference.*

```
[CultureSpecific]
[Display(
    Name = "Specific documents",
    GroupName = SystemTabNames.Content,
    Order = 1)]
public virtual ContentReference SpecificDocument { get; set; }
```

*In my view, I show an icon which I link to different actions, depending on whether the property SpecificDocument is empty or not. The ContentReference property is supposed to contain a file, like a PDF.*

```
@model IPageViewModel<SpacePage>

<div class="row">

   @if (Model.CurrentPage.SpecificDocument != null)
   {
      <a class="image" href="#"> </a>                                
   }
   else
   {
      <a class="icon" href="some action if the property is empty"></a> 
   }
</div>
```

**My question:**

If SpecificDocument property is not null, how do I *href* to the specific *Content* in the *ContentReference property*?

**Clarification:** When a user clicks the icon it either opens the SpecificDocument (PDF) in a window or downloads it.

Bear in mind that I am new to EPiServer development.

Regards,
Chris

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use **UrlResolver.Current** to get the URL of a content reference:

```
var url = UrlResolver.Current.GetUrl(CurrentPage.SpecificDocument)
```

Some in-depth info on different URLs available: http://world.episerver.com/blogs/Linus-Ekstrom/Dates/2014/2/The-three-rendering-modes-of-EPiServer/

Also, you may want to use **ContentReference.IsNullOrEmpty** instead of just null-checking the property, to ensure the property is set.

Comment: Thank you, Ted! Exactly what I was looking for. Will read up on the blog you posted.

/Chris